# Python Derivative Project

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, derivative

I am working on a project which I am trying to alter a derivative function I found online.

I was going to create a function which proves the derivative as `x` approaches `0`, this is what I have but i would like to loop it to have the value of h change:

```
#derivative calc

def f(x):
    return x**2

def derivative(x):
    h = .001
    rise = f(x+h)-f(x)
    run = h
    slope = rise/run
    return slope
z=int(input("please enter value of x:"))
a=derivative(z)
print(a)

def f(x):
    return x**2

def derivative(x):
    h = .0001
    rise = f(x+h)-f(x)
    run = h
    slope = rise/run
    return slope
z=int(input("please enter value of x:"))
a=derivative(z)
print(a)

def f(x):
    return x**2

def derivative(x):
    h = .00001
    rise = f(x+h)-f(x)
    run = h
    slope = rise/run
    return slope
z=int(input("please enter value of x:"))
a=derivative(z)
print(a)

def f(x):
    return x**2

def derivative(x):
    h = .000001
    rise = f(x+h)-f(x)
    run = h
    slope = rise/run
    return slope
z=int(input("please enter value of x:"))
a=derivative(z)
print(a)

def f(x):
    return x**2

def derivative(x):
    h = .0000001
    rise = f(x+h)-f(x)
    run = h
    slope = rise/run
    return slope
z=int(input("please enter value of x:"))
a=derivative(z)
print(a)
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: And why on earth have you defined the same function 5 times?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like homework, so I'll just give you a hint:

If you want to vary `h`, make it be a parameter of the function.

Thus your code should look like:

```
def derivative(x,h):
    #body of your function, slightly modified
```

While your at it, let `f` itself be a parameter so that the same code can numerically differentiate different functions irrespective of what they are named. So your definition can begin:

```
def derivative(f,x,h):
    #body of your function, slightly modified
```

You can then use a for-loop to loop through various `h`. For example, the following loop "proves" that the derivative of `sin(x)` at 0 is 1:

```
for n in range(5):
    h = 10**-n
    print("h =",h,"=>",derivative(math.sin,0,h))
```

Output (once `derivative` has been defined appropriately):

```
h = 1 => 0.8414709848078965
h = 0.1 => 0.9983341664682815
h = 0.01 => 0.9999833334166665
h = 0.001 => 0.9999998333333416
h = 0.0001 => 0.9999999983333334
```

As far as the rest of your code goes -- why assume that `x` is an `int`? It would be better to make it a float since you are doing floating-point operations. Thus your input line should probably look more like

```
z=float(input("please enter value of x:"))
```

Comment: Thank you that is somewhat helpful but I am still struggling with it...

Comment: It is good to struggle sometimes. No other way to learn.